# How do I fix a 401 Authentication Failed during oauth redirect to client with Spring Cloud Security?

Tags: spring, oauth, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2

I have an `Oauth2` `ui-server` (client) and an `auth-server`.  The `ui-server` is the entrypoint into the application.

This is my client's `application.yml`, which is using the `Spring Cloud Security` `@EnableOAuth2Sso` annotation.

```
security:
  sessions: ALWAYS
  oauth2:
    client:
      accessTokenUri: https://<auth-server>/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: https://<auth-server>/oauth/authorize
      clientId: ui
      clientSecret: <client secret>
      scope: ui
      pre-established-redirect-uri: https://<ui-server>/login
      registered-redirect-uri: http://<ui-server>/login
      use-current-uri: false
    resource:
      jwt:
        keyValue: <keyValue>
```

My `auth-server` is running `Spring Security Oauth` with the `@EnableAuthorizationServer` annotation. This is the relavent client row in the database:

```
client_id, resource_ids, client_secret, scope, authorized_grant_types, web_server_redirect_uri,             authorities, access_token_validity, refresh_token_validity, additional_information, autoapprove
'ui',      NULL,        'ui-secret',   'ui',   'authorization_code',  'https://<ui-server>/login', NULL,        NULL,                  NULL,                   NULL,                   'ui'
```

When I hit my `ui-server`, it redirects to my `auth-server` login page.  I fill out the form, but on the redirect to `https://<ui-server>/login?code=<code>&state=<state>`, I get a `401 Authentication Failed: Could not obtain access token`.  There appears to be no error messages in my logs.

I had this error on my `localhost`, but another SO post told me the problem was due to the `host` being the same for both servers, i.e. `localhost`.  It said I should fix by setting a `contextPath` for the `auth-server`.  However, in this case, setting a `contextPath` does not help.

Does anyone know how to resolve the `401` on the `Oauth` redirect to client?

Comment: Did you ever get around this issue?

Comment: I did, but I have no idea what I did!  I stopped using JWT, and then I stopped using spring in favor of implementing a new oauth server in AWS Lambda.